# how can my modal know index in row clicked reactjs

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I am a beginner in this language I've used php before. 
So the table has a button and when I clicked the button it only read the first row it won't read the other rows, In php ive used the function attr so it will read the other clicked row and here at reactjs i don't know how please help

```
return <tr key={i} >
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address}</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={ this.props.onClick }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Update</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> <input type="text"value={ d.Employee_Name} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" value={ d.Address} />  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </tr>
}
```

Comment: can you show, how you are using map to create the ui ?

Comment: @MayankShukla {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}

Comment: Just pass the id of the object to onClick function like this <button onClick={ this.props.onClick, id }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Update</button>

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of item clicked, you need to `bind` the index to `onClick` function for each element, like this:

```
<td>
    <center>
         <button ... onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) }></button>
    </center> 
</td>
```

**Note**: replace `...` by other properties you are using.

Whenever you click on any item, index i will get passed to `this.props.onClick` method, you can check that by using `console.log` in parent `onClick` function, like this:

```
onClick(index){
   console.log(index); // it will print the index of item clicked
}
```

Comment: still..  it only reads the first row of the table, in the modal's input...

Comment: you are not getting the different indexes in onClick function ?

Comment: sorry im just new to this i dont know what you meant but i put what you told me

Comment: i am saying after binding the value i with onClick function (as i mention in snippet), when you are clicking on button, are you not getting the value i in that function ??

Comment: it doesn't do anything, they told me i should call the id from api for the modal to read it but i don't know how